Juego subido a la Play store no son compatibles
Subí un Juego a google play y por alguna razón hay movíles que no pueden descargar el juego y les esta saliendo que su Telefono No es compatible con esta aplicación, lo subí a través de play console, tengo todos los dispositivos habilitados es más uno de ellos es compatible, pero aún así no deja descargar y en otro lo descargo antes se actualizo y ahora no es compatible.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
